# How to use Python requests to filter the result on a web page?

Tags: python, filter, get, python-requests

I am working on getting information from `https://www.corporationwiki.com/search/results?term=jim%20smith`(just a random name I pick, please don't mind), I want to filter the result by using the drop-down menu and select a State.

However, the web page doesn't implement 'States' as a parameter, which means the URL doesn't change after I select a state.

I tried passing `params` into `requests.get()`, the result didn't change.

Here's the code I used:

```
url = 'https://www.corporationwiki.com/search/results?term=jim%20smith'
r = requests.get(url, params= dict(
    query="web scraping",
    page=2, states = 'Maryland'),timeout = 5)
```

There's no error message, however, it also didn't show me the filtered result.

Can anyone help me passing the right parameters so I can filter the result by states?

Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like the site probably loads asynchronously, you will need to use browser automation like selenium to automate the dropdown menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it looks like the website does implement state as parameter. The exact name is "stateFacet".

You can just send your get request to:

```
https://www.corporationwiki.com/search/withfacets?term=jim%20smith&stateFacet=state_code
```

Just replace `state_code` with the correct value. For example:

https://www.corporationwiki.com/search/withfacets?term=jim%20smith&stateFacet=de

This link will filter with the state Delaware.

Comment: Not OP but how did you find that out?

Comment: @R10t-- When you select a state in the drop down menu, a get request with this parameter is being sent in the background. You can see this request using your browser developer tools (exist in most browsers, I used google chrome).

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint doesn't support it, then you cannot get it via URL. You will need to look into more complicated methods of doing so, or figure out the correct URL parameter if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with requests. You will probably need to use something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simulate clicking the dropdown and picking the filter(s) you want. This is because that dropdown's logic is all javascript which cannot be done through the URL request.